# sending a string to the server and receiving not updated response

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm writing an app for android in Java, and the server side also with Java.
The connection is through sockets. To send strings to the server I'm using asyncTask as follows:

```
public static void send(String content) throws IOException {
    mConnectionHandler.new AsyncSendToServer().execute(content);
}

private class AsyncSendToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        out.println(params[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now the response from the server is done as follows:

```
public static String receive() {
    mConnectionHandler.new AsyncReceiveFromServer().execute();
    return serverResponse;
}

private class AsyncReceiveFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        serverResponse = result;
    }
}
```

Because the methods are async, the serverResponse does not get the appropriate value in receive(). When I execute  AsyncReceiveFromServer, receive() return the value of serverResponse before it's get updated in the asyncTask. What can I do in order to send the updated serverResponse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute your AsyncReceiveFromServer from the onPostExecute of your AsyncSendToServer.
This way, you are absolutely certain that the Send has finished.

Comment: It is still doesnt work. serverResponse is returned before he gets his new value from Send, because it is executed simultaneously.

Comment: Then you're not doing what I'm saying or something else is wrong ... if you don't start getting your serverresponse until the send has finished (which it must have, if you start the receive inside the onPostExecute() of the send) it can never be executed simultaneously.

Comment: OK I managed to fix it. On the receive() I'm just returning AsyncReceiveFromServer result, which waiting for it to finish it computation. Thanks alot!